# check lists have identical elements using python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

Here is my code for comparing two lists and print the output as 1 in lis1 is matched at position 2 in list2 so on..Can you please let me know how i can use nested for loops and break and continue statements
.Also any feasible approach to do this solution

```
def Iter(l1,l2):
    for i in range(len(l1)):
        for j in range(len(l2)):
            if l1[i]==l2[j]:
                print("matched at %d position"%l2[j])
            break

                    
l1=[1,2,3,4,5]
l2=[3,4,1,2,5]
Iter(l1,l2)
```

Comment: You are already using nested `for` loops. Can you be more specific about what help you need?

Comment: i want the outputs to printed as 1 in l1 is matched at position 2 of l2 likewise for all the numbers. Iam trying to solve in my approch as i want to understand the working of break,continue statements and else.But i ended up getting errors

Comment: @RGV what errors? Please always be specific and precise about your problems. Don't make people guess at what is wrong.

Comment: matched at 3 position is the output  printed upon execution  and i am struck what i need to add in my code using else,break,continue statements to get an insight

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you just need to find the position of each item in first list, in the second list.
you can just use one loop to iterate in your first list. for each element you can check if that element exist in the second loop and if so, report the index:

```
def Iter(l1,l2):
for i,x in enumerate(l1):
    try:
      print(f"position {i} in first list matched at position {l2.index(x)} in second list")
    except ValueError:
      continue
```

the "try" and "except" part is just to handle the error that will arise when you try to use l2.index() on an element that exists in l1 but not l2.

Comment: Don't check `if x in l2` and then call `l2.index(x)`, that' redundant, just use `l2.index(x)`

Comment: But then if the element is not in the second list, you'll get a value error.

Comment: So what? Use `try-except` to handle the error. That's what exception handling is for. Don't do something less efficient to avoid handling an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use one loop **if both the arrays are of equal length**.

```
def Iter(l1,l2):
    for i in range(len(l1)):
      if l1[i]==l2[i]:
        print("matched at %d position"%l2[i])
     
l1=[1,2,3,4,5]
l2=[1,2,1,2,5]
Iter(l1,l2)
```

output:

```
matched at 1 position
matched at 2 position
matched at 5 position
```

Comment: you should use `zip` for this, not `range(len(...))`

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is time-inefficient, it's quadratic time. You can do it in linear time if you allow for linear space. Create a *mapping* of elements in `list2` to their indices:

```
# assuming unique elements, you can modify to use a lists of indices as values to handle 

l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [3,4,1,2,5]

index_map = {val:i for i, val in enumerate(l2)}
for val in l1:
    if val in l2:
        print(f"Matched {val} at position {index_map[val]}")
```